# set the page size with UITableView and paging.enabled=YES (or other way ?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm struggling with this problem, although I'm close to the solution, but I guessing I'm missing something.

Here is the situation :

I have UITableView with 30 cells, and one section header (if it's helpful..).
The table size is exactly the size of 3 rows.

The mission : to let the user scroll 3 rows everytime, exactly 3.
I set the pagingEnabled=YES.

What happens is :
"page 1" - 3 rows - ok (rows 0-2)

swiping to "page 2" - next 3 rows - ok (row 3-5)

swiping to "page 3" - and the paging is not good, either skiping row 6 and showing row 7-9
or the page is stopped in the middle of the cell of 6 (also tried to move the scroll to complete cell visibilty with scolling end event, but it skips some of the rows on some pages)

Any ideas how to fix the situation, every page = 3 rows only ,without skipping or showing half of cell ?

I don't mind if the way will be without pagingEnabled=YES.

I arrived at the conclusion this is basic thing I will use in the future , and I think a lot of others will use the solution that other friends will give here.

Thanks.

Comment: What a interesting UITableView usage. It looks like the section header is making your content size bigger than cell.height * 30, so the paging offset is going wrong. Maybe you should use NSLog to check what is the exactly contentSize of your tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Never thought of using this property in a Table View. 
Since it is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, try instead to use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods and calculate where to stop.
A good place to start can be in `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`. and return the offset yourself.

P.S.
from the documentation:

> This method is not called when the value of the scroll view’s
>   pagingEnabled property is YES. Your application can change the value
>   of the targetContentOffset parameter to adjust where the scrollview
>   finishes its scrolling animation.